# dismiss view without animation after app started dismissing the view with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Is there a way to cancel dismissing the view with animation and then dismiss the same view without animation??

So here is what it's going on:
On my iPad application, I have a root controller that presents settings view controller. Either on presentation/dismissal by users, the settings view appear/disappear with animation.

However, there's a case when user gets kicked out of the app and the app should display login view. So if the rootViewContoller has presentedViewController(like the settings view above), I do the following:

```
   [rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
   [rootViewController presentViewController:logInViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
   }];
```

Now the problem is a rare case when user dismisses the settings view controller just before the app kicks the user out. When the app his the code above, because the settings view is already being dismissed app throws a warning

`"Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UINavigationController:> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"`

and that code does not run, which in result, the log in view is not presented afterwards.

One way I tried is to just wait until the dismissal with animation is done and do presentViewController:animated:completion: with delay (with arbitrary time frame). This works, but I don't really like this method since that 'arbitrary time frame' is not guaranteed to work all the time (or if I make it too long then the user will have to wait that time). And I also don't like the code is quite complex with using NSInvocation.

So I wonder if there is a way to force dismiss the view quickly(without animation) that is being dismissed with animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate UIWindow for your login view, and make it the keywindow. When you're done, you can switch back to the other window, in which case the Settings screen will still be visible.  Generally when I'm using an app, if I do something, then leave the app and come back, I want the "something" to still be there. I think this is exactly that sort of use case.